# how to get last value shown yAxis highcharts in current version in a simple way?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a simple way in current highcharts version of getting the last value in the Y axis?
I already know how to get the highest value with getExtremes(), but I need the last value in the Y axis to feed the last value of a time series into a gauge. Additionaly I would like to calculate current yearly speed and feed it in another gauge, by calculating the difference between the last value and the value exactly one year earlier. Additionally the same as before for an acceleration gauge by calculating the speed difference between the current speed and the speed last year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you want to get the last yAxis label value or the last point value, but here is an example of how to achieve it:

```
// last label value
var data = mainChart.yAxis[0].max;


/* // the last point value 
var data = mainChart.series[0].points[mainChart.series[0].points.length - 1].y
 */
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1702dogs/

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thank you for your answer, it works! How about calculating the speed of change in the Y axis series? What is the easiest way to achieve this?. The samples are time stamped in the X axis. I was thinking of calculating speed as this Month's Y axis average divided into this Month's last year average. For example we are in December 2019, so the real time speed indicator should be calculated as the average of Y values for December 2019 divided into the average of Y values for December 2018.

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tuwm4013/

Comment: I made a mistake I meant substracting the two averages instead of dividing them as I want to calculate the yearly speed,  but your example is useful just the same. 

The challenge is how do you select in the series (that was loaded with GetJson() from a remote server), the samples  from  a given month and year (the x axis coordinate) without having to resort to xAxis.setExtremes().
Following your jsfiddle example we would need to do it two times, one to fill your dataDecember2019 variable, and another to fill your  dataDecember2018 variable.

Comment: There must be something faster, I suspect that doing it this way must be very slow, is there a better way? 

The end goal of all this is creating a new series  with yearly speed of change from 1959 to 2019, we want to calculate the speed of change per year, starting January 1960, Month after Month. That new series would be the second Y Axis series  and would be displayed on the same time graph as another curve.

In the original Y axis series, the samples happen weekly in the first years, when we get to 1980 they become daily, is this a problem?

Comment: I mean for the second Y axis curve with the speed of change per year

Comment: @Catalansurfer I think that a better solution will be doing all those mathematics operations on the backend site and just fetching the calculated data for charts.

Comment: I can't! :( I don't have access to the backend I can only use the getJson API to get their data for the series. So, I have to do it in Javascript l! Please advise on the most efficient way to achieve this in Javascript, thank you! For your Xmas present!

Comment: Are you able to reproduce a sample of your data?

Comment: [Date.UTC(1960,0,2),315.72],
[Date.UTC(1960,0,9),316.4],
[Date.UTC(1960,0,16),316.73],
[Date.UTC(1960,0,23),316.57],
[Date.UTC(1960,0,30),316.68],

Comment: [Date.UTC(1959,0,3),315.24],
[Date.UTC(1959,0,10),315.5],
[Date.UTC(1959,0,17),315.69],
[Date.UTC(1959,0,24),315.86],
[Date.UTC(1959,0,31),315.42],

Comment: Ok, so then why don't you make data calculation before chart initializing? I mean when you got a data with GetJson you will need to create a function which will calculate the yearly speed change for each month and put them in the array. Use the map function to do it. And when data will be ready then initialize the chart.

Comment: That's how the javascript begins:.getJSON("https://www.example.com/data.php?callback=?", function (data)
  {
        var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate over time'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                    'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the

Comment: How can I insert the map() function with that coding approach? Can I use the chart.series[0].points var as the input array for map()  and use chart.series[1].points as the output array?

Comment: I think that it will be better to do all the calculations before chart initialization, so before var chart = {... Could you reproduce this case on some online editor? It will be much easier. And please prepare sample data.

Comment: Yes I will ! just allow  for some time to set this up online on jsfiddle

Comment: Here it goes Sebastian https://jsfiddle.net/catalansurfer/0cLojshv/ I have no problem in putting the code before chart initialization after all, the difficulty is in the calculation itself

Comment: Here is my idea how to get the average values for each month for each year, see: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3ox6ykfs/

Comment: It works fine Sebastian!, but I don't seem to be able to do the last step, which is transforming the years array to add the average monthly speed calculated as previous year same month value minus this year and month value. can you help with that? Alternatively if that is easier, instead of adding the speed to the years array, the years array could be rewritten with speed instead of the current values

Comment: Yes. I managed to integrate it and make it work. The only thing is that in the real getJson imported data, the years before 1959 have months without samples and even years without samples, so I had to use the slice() method to remove all years before 1959 , which is not ideal. What little change would be needed for your solution to work if some months don't have samples, making the value of the non-sample month equal to the last month with sample, be it from same year or last year with samples?

Comment: like the  data sample here https://jsfiddle.net/catalansurfer/0cLojshv/7/

Comment: I don't understand - what do you have in mind by saying 'without samples'?

Comment: Starting 1959 there is every Month one of these json "records"or "samples", but before that year there is only one every 5 years or every year:                                  [Date.UTC(1815,0,1),284],
[Date.UTC(1820,0,1),284.2],
[Date.UTC(1825,0,1),284.3],

Comment: I think that slice this part of data, do a wanted calculation and add them back to counted Averages object will be a nice solution

Comment: Ok, now another subject since 2020, the solution doesn't work because there is only sample for january and not for the other Months in 2020 yet. In December the code was working fine because December is the last Month of the year and there were data for all Months in 2019, what change needs the code?

Comment: I think that this conversation is no longer related to using Highcharts library, but with general JavaScripts functionalities. I am afraid I cannot help you more.

Comment: It's ok Sebastian, you are right, you have been extremely generous in this conversation, thank you  :) I managed to fix it myself, although 3d arrays in Javascript are really a nightmare :)